# Laravel passport throwing error: 'Call to a member function createToken() on null'

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-passport

So i'm trying to create an auth repository test using phpunit but i keep getting the error 'Call to a member function createToken() on null'. I think this is due to the RefreshDatabase trait but i'm installing passport on setup so i'm a bit lost. Any help is appreciated!

**AuthRepository test**

```
namespace Tests\Repository;

use App\Contracts\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

   protected $authRepository;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->artisan('passport:install');
        $this->authRepository = app()->make(Auth::class);
    }

    /**
     * Test Successful Login
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testSuccessfulLogin(): void
    {
        $request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
        $request->setMethod('POST');
        $request->replace(['name' => 'test', 'email' => 'test', 'password' => 'testing']);
        $this->authRepository->register($request);

        $request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
        $request->setMethod('POST');
        $request->replace(['email' => 'test', 'password' => 'testing']);
        $this->authRepository->login($request);
    }
}
```

**Test Case**

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setup();

    }
}
```

**AuthRepository**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Contracts\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth as Authenticate;
use App\User;

class AuthRepository implements Auth
{

    public function Register($request)
    {
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))
        ]);

        $user->save();

        return $user;
    }

    public function Login($request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->all();

        if (!Authenticate::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);

        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        $token->save();

        return $tokenResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happened because the controller is trying to get the user data and create a token based on that.

In your case (happened to me too), there was a user variable which pointing the request to get the user credential while the user data is unknown because the user is not yet logged in.

To be clear, please take a look at your code within this line:

```php
$user = $request->user();
$tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
$token = $tokenResult->token;
```

To fix that, change the line of `$user = $request->user()` to this:

```php
$user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();
$tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
$token = $tokenResult->token;
```